# Architecture incompatibility on Apple Silicon when building Docker image through GitHub

Tags: docker

I am building a package on GitHub and publish it on the GH container registry. Upon executing the image I receive the following error:

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 ghcr.io/foo/foo/bar:6d98...7f15                       
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

This is the corresponding section in the workflow yaml. Do I have to build it with a specific flag?

```yaml
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        env:
          CR_PAT: ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }}
        run: |
          docker build --build-arg COMMIT_HASH=${{ steps.commit_hash.outputs.COMMIT_HASH }} -t ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }} .
          echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.repository_owner }} --password-stdin
          docker push ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}
```